# Enable radiobuttonlist in grid on checkbox check

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net

My problem is:

I got data in the front end in this format :

Username : xxxx

First name : xxx

Last Name :  XXX

Authorizations \this is a grid, with chheckbox and radiobtns

Domain             Role

xyz                  User

bnv                 Admin

asd                 User_1

now I need to insert this data back to my table .

1 suggestion i got was : Use `XML` ... right track ? or is there some better way ( haven't worked with `XML`....yet :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to insert bulk data to the database. Apart from `XML` you can also use `SqlBulCopy` class which is very efficient in inserting millions of records to the SQL database. You can find more details on this at MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx